# Dynamic form delete method always removes last added

Tags: flutter, dart

Fair warning I am fairly new to flutter and it will show. I have a form that allows me to dynamically add another form field when selecting the floating action icon however when the fields are created if you press the delete button it will always remove the most recently added item and not the item clicked on. A couple of things I have found is that this happens even if I hardcode an index into my delete method it will still remove the last element. Also **when the onDelete method fires I printed the list and it removes the right item from the list but the Listview builder won't play nice and show what is in the changed list once it's removed.**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_multipage_form/empty_state.dart';
import 'package:flutter_multipage_form/form.dart';
import 'package:flutter_multipage_form/user.dart';

class MultiForm extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_MultiFormState createState() => _MultiFormState();
}

class _MultiFormState extends State<MultiForm> {
List<UserForm> users = [];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      elevation: .0,
      leading: Icon(
        Icons.wb_cloudy,
      ),
      title: Text('REGISTER USERS'),
      actions: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          child: Text('Save'),
          textColor: Colors.white,
          onPressed: onSave,
        )
      ],
    ),
    body: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: [
            Color(0xFF30C1FF),
            Color(0xFF2AA7DC),
          ],
          begin: Alignment.topCenter,
          end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        ),
      ),
      child: users.length <= 0
          ? Center(
              child: EmptyState(
                title: 'Oops',
                message: 'Add form by tapping add button below',
              ),
            )
          : ListView.builder(
              addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
              itemCount: users.length,
              itemBuilder: (_, i) => users[i],
            ),
    ),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      child: Icon(Icons.add),
      onPressed: onAddForm,
      foregroundColor: Colors.white,
    ),
  );
}

///on form user deleted
void onDelete(User _user) {
  setState(() {
    var find = users.firstWhere(
      (it) => it.user == _user,
      orElse: () => null,
    );
    if (find != null) users.removeAt(users.indexOf(find));
  });
}

///on add form
void onAddForm() {
  setState(() {
    var _user = User();
    users.add(UserForm(
      user: _user,
      onDelete: () => onDelete(_user),
    ));
  });
}

///on save forms
void onSave() {
  if (users.length > 0) {
    var allValid = true;
    users.forEach((form) => allValid = allValid && form.isValid());
    if (allValid) {
      var data = users.map((it) => it.user).toList();
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          fullscreenDialog: true,
          builder: (_) => Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                  title: Text('List of Users'),
                ),
                body: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (_, i) => ListTile(
                        leading: CircleAvatar(
                          child: Text(data[i].fullName.substring(0, 1)),
                        ),
                        title: Text(data[i].fullName),
                        subtitle: Text(data[i].email),
                      ),
                ),
              ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
}
```

**Here is the GitHub Repo: https://github.com/matt-end/flutter_multipage_form**